# how to prepare a flow chart using libre office writer

Tags: libreoffice

Short and simply put how to prepare a common flow chart using Libre office.

i just want to prepare a simple flow chart without any complexities.

Comment: Within LibreOffice, the LibreOffice Draw program is best for making flowcharts.

Comment: I know you asked for LibreOffice, but it's capabilities are limited  compared to other options. A good alternative, which is fee but not open source is Yed : www.yworks.com/en/products_yed_about.html

Comment: Or [lucidchart](http://lucidchart.com)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I would strongly suggest you use Libre Office Draw or Impress, not Writer, as it handles shapes much better. Impress also includes connectors. However, if you want to use Writer:

First click `View -> Toolbars -> Drawing`.

[image]

Then click on the `flowcharts` button, on the drawing tool bar. (For ease of use, drag the 3 lines at the bottom to make it into a permanent window.

[image]
[image]

Hovering over each item will show you what it does.

[image]

Click on one, and draw it on the page, then double click on it to type in it.

[image]

Then click on the `Block arrows` (Drag that off as well if you like).

[image]

And draw an arrow.

[image]

Repeat

[image]

My pronouns are He / Him

However, Libreoffice Draw is probably better for this. The icons are all the same, but it is better at handling the shapes than text - if you type something in text it will mess it up, but draw will be okay.

Comment: This is  good answer. But I wish LibreOffice simply includes the 'Connector' tool in Writer so that we don't need to go this hassle.

Comment: [Official help](https://help.libreoffice.org/Impress/Creating_a_Flowchart) talks about **Connectors**. Do you have any idea? Oh! yes got it, it is available in Libreoffice Draw.

Comment: @Pandya actually that’s talking about Impress, the presentation app. Hmm...